# Git .Net files to ignore

Tags: .net, git

What are your best practices for Git with .Net? What files do you ignore and do not add to your project type?

Comment: Related: ".gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and Solutions" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An initial list excludes all [temporary build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhkhh4zs.aspx) files,

```
*.dep *.aps *.vbw *.suo *.obj *.ncb *.plg *.bsc *.ilk 
*.exp *.sbr *.opt *.pdb *.idb *.pch *.res *.user
```

Also the build directories

```
 *\obj
 *\bin
 *\Debug
 *\Release
```

if you use Rehsarper, exclude its directories too

```
 ./Resharp*
```

Plus some special files

```
 Thumbs.db
```

Some people also exclude binary files

```
 *.exe
 *.dll
```

It might be worthwhile considering what you want *to* store in your SCM, rather than a long and possibly never-complete list of exclusions.

Comment: Don't exclude *.dll* if you have 3rd party assemblies in your project though :)

Comment: .user and .suo aren't temporary build files. Additionally, build and binary files are automatically excluded if you ignore obj and bin, which makes for a much shorter ignore list. In .NET solutions, there's no reason to exclude Debug and Release, since both reside in obj/bin, which should be ignored anyway. And ignoring the thumbs.db is, in my opinion, a bit strange since they are simply not there on newer systems (XP legacy). +1 though for the Resharper and the final advice.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really git-specific, but rather applies to any version control.

Ignore the bin and obj folders, and the .user and .suo files (which are user-specific). That is, of course, if you're using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

I exclude all binary and source files that the Visual Studio doesn't need in order to rebuilt the application.
I'm not sure if all VS versions have the same file extensions, but you can experiment if you like.

Eric Sink has a guide for source control, [Source Control HOWTO](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html), and in [Chapter 4: Repositories](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/scm_repositories.html), you can read *What can be stored in a repository?* section, which is related to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Git, but I do ignore files!

```
bin obj *.user *.suo *.log *.vbw *.pdb *mdf *ldf 
_UpgradeReport* UpgradeLog* _ReSharper* *.resharper
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this as a template for all my .net git repos: [.gitignore Gist for .net](https://gist.github.com/2396101)