# Openshift django should i add setup.py install generated files to gitignore?

Tags: python, django, openshift

Hi i'm trying to deploy a simple django app with openshift, i followed this tutorial: 
https://github.com/rancavil/django-openshift-quickstart/wiki/Tutorial-How-create-an-application-with-Django-1.6-on-Openshift

except for the first part where i used openshift's django cartridge instead.
after running the setup.py install it created 3 directories: dist, build and AppName.egg-info

so now the relevant part of my directory stucture looks like this:

```
.
├── build
│   └── bdist.linux-x86_64
├── data
├── dist
│   └── AppName-1.0-py2.7.egg
├── libs
│   └── openshiftlibs.py
├── openshiftlibs.py
├── AppName.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── wsgi
    ├── application
    ├── myproject
```

Since those directories are auto generated my question is should i version them too? better yet can someone please provide a sample gitignore for a django site hosted on openshift? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been searching a little and found this answer is kind of what i was looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14058267/4349619

i did some more tweaking and now my gitignore looks like this:

```
# Django stuff:
*.log
*.pot
local_settings.py

# databases
*.sqlite3

# Sphinx documentation
docs/_build/

# Byte-compiled / optimized / DLL files
__pycache__/
*.py[cod]

# Distribution / packaging
bin/
build/
develop-eggs/
dist/
eggs/
lib/
lib64/
parts/
sdist/
var/
*.egg-info/
.installed.cfg
*.egg

# Installer logs
pip-log.txt
pip-delete-this-directory.txt

# Unit test / coverage reports
.tox/
.coverage
.cache
nosetests.xml
coverage.xml

# Temporary files
*~

# Mr Developer
.project
.pydevproject

# Intellij idea
.idea
*.iml

# Don't know what these are
*.sw[po]
*.bak
*.orig

# PyBuilder
target/
```

i think some of these are not needed but it's ok for now.
feel free to leave suggestions and enhancements :)