# Error fatal: pathspec did not match any files using git rm to remove the pyc file

Tags: python, django, git, tdd

I am currently reading a book called "Test-Driven Development with Python" In chapter1, I have to use

```
git rm -r --cached superlists/__pycache__
```

to remove all the .pyc files, I got the error the same in the title. I have searched many similar problems in this forum, I still cannot figure it out how to solve it. Hope someone could help me. Many Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you need to do this? Unless you actually added the `__pycache__` directory to git in the first place - and I can't see why you would - you wouldn't need to remove it.

Comment: Yes, I did add the .pyc files to git using `git add .`, if you read that book, you will see the author tried to use the same code to remove the .pyc files.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error while doing executing the same command:

Solution 1: 
One of the stackoverflow answers mentions his usual buildout have the have .pyc in the .gitignore file - [link to the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719679)
I did that and then did the "$ git add ." command. It worked and the __pycache__ files were not added.

```python
$echo "*.pyc" >> .gitignore
```

Solution 2: 
I cleaned the staging area for the files to be commited
and then executed the same command. It worked

```python
$git reset
$git rm -r --chached superlists/__pycache__
```

[screenshot for Solution 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zR0j5.png)
 Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your error, `Error fatal: pathspec did not match any files`, means that the pathspec you specified (`superlists/__pycache__`) doesn't match any files that are being tracked by git.

In the previous steps had you added the `__pycache__` files to git?

Are there any `__pycache__` files in the `superlists` directory?  Have you run the `superlists` code?  Perhaps you have your python configured to not output `.pyc` cache files?

What is the output of `ls -a superlists` and `ls -a superlists/__pycache__`?

Comment: Yes, I did add the __pycache__ files to git in the previous step by using `git add .` Actually, this is the output when I run `ls -a superlists` :         __init__.py settings.py urls.py  wsgi.py
__init__.pyc settings.pyc urls.pyc wsgi.pyc.                                              Also this is the code the author used in the book to remove the .pyc files. I have no idea where it went wrong