# what document i need to put in .gitignore when I start a new django project

Tags: django, git

So I want to start a project with django2 and I want to know what kind of doc I can ignore when push them to github.

Comment: You can checkout https://www.gitignore.io for an extensive list of files you can ignore in Django. This list is probably too broad for (most) projects to start with, so you can remove the entries that don't seem relevant at all.

Comment: Thank you, you can add it as the answer so i can validate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended .gitignore file for Python projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719243/recommended-gitignore-file-for-python-projects)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django+gitignore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/) for an extensive list of files you can ignore in Django. This list is probably too broad for (most) projects to start with, so you can remove the entries that don't seem relevant at all.

Answer (score 2):

On a fresh new project it'd be wise to ignore the database and nothing else. 
Then it depends on what other tools you're using. For example if you use coverage, it may be a good idea to ignore its files, and your .gitignore would look like:

```
# SQLite
db.sqlite3

# coverage
htmlcov/**
.coverage
```