# How to ignore the same name directory __pycache__ in a project?

Tags: git, gitignore

The `__pycache__` directory is annoying when working with git updates. Whenever I use `git status`, a lot of .pyc files show up. How can I conveniently list the `__pycache__` folder in my `.gitignore` file so that they won't show up when using `git status`?

For example:

```
core/__pycache__/utils.cpython-36.pyc
core/__pycache__/version.cpython-36.pyc
core/actions/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc
core/actions/__pycache__/action.cpython-36.pyc
```

Do I have to list all the individual `__pycache__`files into the gitignore file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ignoring any 'bin' directory on a git project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470572/ignoring-any-bin-directory-on-a-git-project)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best practices for adding .gitignore file for Python projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719243/best-practices-for-adding-gitignore-file-for-python-projects)

Comment: It sounds like you have *already committed* the `*,pyc` files in some existing commits. These existing commits can never be changed—those pycache files are in them forever. You can make new commits that are like the old commits, but don't have the `*.pyc` files in them, and switch to using the new commits and never use the old ones ever again, which is viable as long as other people on the project also switch over.

Answer (score 89):

Use `**/__pycache__/` this to ignore all **pycache** folder across the repo

Comment: This works with `tree --gitignore` whereas just `__pycache__/` only ignores the top level one.

Answer (score 41):

`__pycache__/`. The ending slash indicates it is a directory and will ignore any files beneath it.

Comment: You don't need `**`. You can just say `__pycache__/`.

Comment: I added "__pycache__" to my .gitignore and then run "git status", it still displays all the .pyc file. It doesn't effect.

Comment: @marlon Displays them how exactly?

Comment: In untracked files? What about `__pycache__/*` ?

Comment: @marlon The asterisk is not needed. I guess you should take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: If you've ALREADY added the `__pycache__` directory files (via `git add ...`), then running `git status` will still show the `__pycache__` directory files - even after your `.gitignore` updates. You'll need to reset (`git reset`) and then run `git status` to see if the .gitignore updates worked. Afterward, you can then add the files you want to commit.

Comment: @cjn You should absolutely write that as answer, everyone searching this question up will think that adding this line will fix their git. Help future readers out!

Comment: @cjn I commited __pycache__ folder lots of commits before, i'm ignoring __pycache_folder but doesn't work cause i made several commits before with that folder added.

Answer (score 8):

I used this command in my root directory and it worked for me

```
git rm --cached */__pycache__/*
```

Answer (score 6):

I only wrote:

```
__pycache__
```

Worked for me and now ignoring  all file in `__pycache__`  in any directory.

Don't forget to delete all later cached files with `__pycache__` .

Answer (score 2):

For windows users, please check that your .gitignore file uses \n or \r\n as EOL (end of line), I had \r in my .gitignore file and the file rules were completely ignored in the windows version (git version 2.34.1.windows.1), in which case `__pycache__/` was also ignored.
After changing the EOL to \n, all the `__pycache__` folders were ignored as expected.