# Git Ignore All __pycache__ Directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I just follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56309100/how-to-ignore-the-same-name-directory-pycache-in-a-project) solution to add `__pycache__/` in my `.gitignore` but it doesn't work. All directory with format `__pycache__` still appear in my `git status`

[image]

Comment: Since it says `modified` for those `__pycache__` directories, that means those files are already committed and tracked in your repo, and adding it to gitignore won't "un-commit" them.

Comment: Or the more general: [How can I make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked, but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/2745495)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you have already committed the **pycache**/ folders before, when you add it to gitignore it can't ignore them, they have already been pushed. You, therefore, need to remove them from your repository using `git rm -r <path to __pycach__>` and commit this change. Then the gitignore should work.