# What should be included in a windows phone 7 gitignore file?

Tags: git, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-express

I plan to start working with WP7/MS Visual Studio Express 2010 and I would like to know the files I can safely include in my gitignore file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing Windows Phone specific you should be ignoring. Use the same rules as you would for any other visual studio solution
see: [.gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions)