# Adding files to Git using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a **LARGE** project with some files I created (> 100 files). All these files are scattered in many of the project modules. I want to add some if these files to Git, but not all of them (some of these files are not meant to be added to Git). IDEA shows me a window with files when I want to commit directories at once where I can choose files for a partial commit. Is there a similar window where I can see what files will be added to Git and deselect unwanted files before actually adding them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. You can use 'Changes tool -> Local Tab' located in bottom of IntelliJ.
There you can separate changes logically withs 'Changesets'

Also there exist different possibilities to control your ignored git files:

- [use .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/gitignore-file-syntax)
- use IntelliJ's ignore

[image]
[image]

More detailed info you can get from official [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/local-tab.html).