# eclipse intellij can use Github for same project

Tags: eclipse, git, intellij-idea

Is it possible to create one project in GitHub,  and two teams who are using different IDE like Eclipse and Intellij can configure project with github and can work simultaneously on same project? 
I have searched it but not able to find proper solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you even can version:

- your [.project and .classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2819639/6309) (eclipse)
- and [your `.idea` folder (intellij)](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23393067)

And both set of IDE-specific files would ignore each others: one could use the Eclipse settings without realizing there is an IntelliJ IDEA project, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible.
Most IDE's do create some specific project folders, where the IDE does store Data for your project. As example local build paths and so on.

Git provides the .gitignore file.

In this file you can specify which folders and files git will ignore. As example IDE Based files and folders. Due that every developer can his favourite IDE and no local IDE based files will be in the Git Porject itself.

Most IDE's will update or crate the .gitignore File automatic when they do find an git folder in the project.

What files you have to add to the .gitignore file is differs from IDE to IDE. It also depends on what Programm language your Project is written in.

Here you can find more about the gitignore file:

[How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

http://www.bmchild.com/2012/06/git-ignore-for-java-eclipse-project.html

Comment: Thank you very much for in-depth explanation.

Comment: Ah just to complete it. The .gitignore file can be used for other usefull stuff like Config files.

Comment: To prevent everyone commit the local config file with, local SQL Connection data and similar stuff. Create a sample Config and simply let GIT ignore the actual Config. If your project goes to a testing or live area it will make it easier, due you can just take the sample config and write the new area values in it. 

The same is for new developers who may join. They can just take the sample config and insert their local test values.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there no limits on IDEs and number of team members, check [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Basic_Tutorial:_Adding_a_project_to_version_control) for Eclipse
and [this](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Basic_Tutorial:_Adding_a_project_to_version_control) for IntelliJ

Comment: Thanks Anatoly.. its really useful.