# Eclipse and Intellij project with GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github, intellij-idea

I am trying to set a project that can be used by developers using Intellij or Eclipse on Github. I am not sure I am doing it right.

I know I need the .classpath and project from Eclipse and *.iml for Intellij but I have concerns about the project structure (I am using Maven). In Intellij, everything is fine and I can commit the project as I usually do and the top level contains src folders, pom.xml and so on. With Eclipse the top level is the project folder itself and then inside that folder, I see the pom.xml and src folder.

I am looking for details and found this other SO ([eclipse intellij can use Github for same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506062/eclipse-intellij-can-use-github-for-same-project#)) but this is really about the file and not the structure.

Can you please help with the project structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to push are only `src` folder and `pom.xml` file. All another files and folders should be added to `.gitignore`. Then you can clone repository and open it in Eclipse or Intellij as existing project (in Intellij: New -> Project from existing sources) or just open it from version control: New -> Project from version control -> git. Also you can add this instructions to `README.md` file.

Comment: Thanks Stepan your answer. That is what I was trying and it didn't work for Eclipse but worked all fine with IntelliJ. I ended up creating everything in IntelliJ and I found they have a functionality to export project to Eclipse (Not sure if it is the paid version only). That created the 2 files  required for Eclipse. I exported to Github and imported the project as is in Eclipse. Worked fine. Yes, I am carrying stuff from IntelliJ and Eclipse around but it works fine.
Kudos to IntelliJ. I have been only using Eclipse until last year and was just giving IntelliJ a try. Much more robust IMO.