# correct usage of .gitignore (for file types)

Tags: gitignore

when I type git status I get the following message:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   .DS_Store
    modified:   README.txt
    modified:   lib/PriceSeries.rb

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    MM8 Prices.pdf
    prices from EH.xlsx
```

I want to be able to say `git add .`, without adding the untracked files. I believe that the .gitignore file is supposed to be for this. My .gitignore file (in the .git folder) looks like this:

```
#Ignore all xlsx files
.xlsx

#Ignore all pdf file
.pdf
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ignore files in a directory in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Comment: I'm already doing that, but it seems that git is ignoring my .gitignore file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prefix your extensions with `*`:

```
#Ignore all xlsx files
*.xlsx

#Ignore all pdf file
*.pdf
```

[Update] Also, `.gitignore` must be in the root of your project, not under `.git`

Comment: Doesn't help, do I need to reset something, or clear caches or something?

Comment: .gitignore is not supposed to be under .git, but directly in the root of your project.

Comment: If it helped, please choose my answer.