# How to make .gitignore ignore files?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a .gitignore file with the following contents:

```
.vs/
```

I run the following commands

```
git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'adding ignore file'
```

In my .vs folder, I have a text file named test.txt.

When I type `git status`, I see the following output

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .vs/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Run `git status -uall` to see which files *within* `.vs/` are being not-ignored; but in general, git will look inside `.vs/` despite the ignore directive if there are already some tracked files *within* `.vs/` so that Git *must* look inside `.vs/` to look at the *tracked* files. Use `git ls-files --stage` to see *all* your tracked files (note that this produces a lot of output in a big repository!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208246/chinese-characters-in-gitignore) (Visual Studio was adding Chinese characters to my .gitignore also)

My .gitignore was saved with unicode encoding.

This is because I created my .gitignore file via PowerShell like so

```
".vs/" > .gitignore
```

I did this because explorer doesn't let you create a text file with a leading period. My solution:

```
".vs/" | Out-File -Encoding ascii -FilePath .gitignore
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think from the logs is that you have added the folder in .gitignore but still since it was committed earlier you want to remove it.

If is present in earlier commits and you want to remove it. You can use :-

```
git rm --cached .vs/
```

this will mark the folder as deleted from index but it will be unchanged in local.

Then use:

```
git commit -m "<Msg showing removing file from git tracking.>"
```

I have taken a certain assumption, Please clarify if it's not what you need.

Comment: No need, .vs/ is enough to ignore a folder content.

Comment: No need, the git status shows .vs was not already added to the index.

Comment: Yes VonC, I am that's why not sure, what @yxrkt really needs.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use correct patterns. `.vs` must be in same directory as `.gitignore`, if not, correct the path.
2. Do commit `.gitignore`, so that others benefit from it.
3. If something is already included (tracked) by git, and you later add it to `.gitignore`, it won't cause git to forget it. For this:

   1. Use `git rm --cached <filePath>` for file(s)
   2. Use `git rm -r --cached <dirPath>` for a directory

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to add `.gitignore` to the index and commit it for said file to be effective.

A `git status` done after creating/updating a `.gitignore` will work.

Second, make sure your `.gitignore` is at the same level (or above) as `.vs/` (not inside it)

Third, check its eol (end of line, make sure it is linux-style)