# gitignore file inside a directory or a directory

Tags: git

I have this file structure

[image]

Inside Android directory there is pizzaSample directory that contains .idea that i want to ignore.(Android/pizzaSample/.idea)

What i have tried inside my .gitignore file to ignore a directory or a file is as follows

```
Android/
Android/pizzaSample/
Android/pizzaSample/.idea/misc.xml
```

the above code does not ignore any of the file or the Android directory itself.Can someone help what should i do to ignore a file or a directory?

**UPDATED**

i tried to add a dummy folder(dummyfolder) that contains a dummy file(dummyfile.txt)
and added a single line of my .gitignore file

```
      Android/
      Android/pizzaSample/
      Android/pizzaSample/.idea/misc.xml
      dummyfolder/
```

the code dummyfolder/ ignores the intire folder including dummyfile.txt
and even dummyfolder/* will also do the work.. but i dont understand why when i put Android/ or Android/* in my .gitignore does not work.

This is the file that i want to ignore
[image]

Comment: Try adding a star `*` at the beginning and end of each line.

Comment: See: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git

Comment: i have tried adding * but it does not solve my problem

Comment: Try using `git check-ignore` to debug your .gitignore file.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore

Comment: if you want to ignore .idea file only, then please only keep "Android/pizzaSample/.idea" in .gitignore not all three. An if you want to ignore everything in the directory Android/pizzaSample/*

Comment: i have update my question.can you try to look at it?

Comment: @love I have tried that also..but it does not work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 4):

If a file should be ignored, but is not, try first to remove it, in case it was already versioned (which seems to be the case, since its status is "modified").

```
git rm --cached -- Android/pizzaSample/.idea/misc.xml
```

Then check with `git status` if the file show up