# how to remove files untracked files from git console

Tags: git

i a new git user. When i created a project, there was some files which said to be tracked. I want to remove them from tracked files list not from project itself. Please, help me.

Answer (score 2):

Create `.gitignore` file for this with the files to be ignored listed there.

- [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)
- [How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Important:

- [Ignoring files already tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4308645/3364821)