# How to push an existing Android project to GitHub repo using .gitignore file?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, android-studio, github

I am developing my Android app on `Eclipse`. It works fine and run properly. But, I want to migrate to `Android-Studio`. Here is what I am doing:

1. Create a repo in `GitHub` with `.gitignore`, a `README.md` and `LICENSE` files
2. From within my project folder run the following commands:

   - `git init`
   - `git add .`
   - `git pull git-url master`
   - `git init` (again)
   - `git add .` (again)
   - `git commit -m "First commit"`
   - `git remote add origin git-url`
   - `git push -u origin master`
3. From `Android-Studio`, I checkout the project from Git
4. Run the app from Android-Studio (after alot of configrations)

---

My concern is that **ALL** my project files and folders are pushed to the remote repo at `GitHub`, including for example: `bin\` and `.settings\` folders. Meanwhile, I only need to push the important and platform independenet files because I work in both windows/mac systems and in differnet locations (hence, this is the reason behind using version-control).

My questions are:

1. How to `pull` the files on GitHub first, and then use `.gitignore` to `push` the "important and platform independenet" files from my project folder into `GiHub`
2. What is the recommended method to export a project from `Eclipse` to `Android-Studio` while using GitHub ?! should I:

   - checkout the project from Git (as I am doing now) ?
   - use `Eclipse Export Tool` ?
   - or `clone` the project first into a directoty and then loaded into `Android-Studio` as an existing project ?

Answer (score 0):

- You can pull your files by `git pull origin master` command from GitHub.
- Add the name of the directory/file in `.gitignore` file you don't want to push. [see more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8527650/4133798)
- You can `clone` the project first into a directory then load it in `Android-Studio`.