# (Git) Ignoring a single file within a folder

Tags: git, gitignore

Sorry if it sounds like a very simple question. But I'm still beginner. I already ignored `.gitignore` file itself and everything inside `.idea` folder. This is my `.gitignore` file:

```
\.gitignore
.idea/**
```

I'm working on a web project and trying to ignore a single file within a folder: `config/db.php`

but can't reach it. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Please choose tags correctly. This is a git and gitignore question, and not PHP or web.

Comment: I did add **config/db.php** to **.gitignore** but nothing was changed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git

Comment: I found @RïshïKêshKümar 's comment useful for myself and already upvoted )). And thanks for your answer too man. I'm upvoting your answer too. Thanks )))

Comment: @Sherzod Ah... got it. Have marked this as a duplicate then :)

Answer (score 2):

First, it seems that you’ve already committed the files which you want to ignore. In that case, do:

```
git rm -rf -—cached .idea/ config/db.php
```

Next, correct your `.gitignore` file to have the following entries:

```
.gitignore
.idea/
config/db.php
```

Now, commit the changes in your `.gitignore` file:

```
git add .gitignore && git commit -m “Correct ignore files”
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably already tracking the file. From the main page:

```
Files already tracked by Git are not affected;
```

So you first need to remove the file, and if you try to commit it again, you will get a warning.