# How to use git branch for refactoring legacy code?

Tags: git

If I want to refactor the legacy code then I need write tests for the code.So I make a new branch called 'refactor'.I will make a tests folder and some tests file in it.

But I found that when I finish the refactoring and want to merge to the master branch I need to merge tests folder and its files to master branch.

I do not want to merge these tests files to my master branch.

> I want to keep the tests file and some other dev folders for the
>   'refactor' branch.Because maybe I need to fix some bug under this
>   'refactor' branch with those files.

How should I do?

Comment: Do you need to keep them?   (this i a basic git-usage question, and probably duplicate)

Comment: I want to keep the tests file and some other dev folders for the 'refactor' branch.Because maybe I need to fix some bug under this 'refactor' branch with those files.

Comment: Probably this topic is what you're looking for:  how to ignore files in git https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git

Comment: You just need to put the files in the `.gitignore`. [See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

From `master`:

```
git merge --no-commit refactorbranch
git reset path/to/my/unwanted/tests
git reset path/to/unwanted/data
git commit -m "Merged refactoring"
```