# How to exclude files in git repo?

Tags: git, laravel, github

On my laravel installation i have an envoirement file and a folder of XML files that i need, but don't want to include in my git REPO.

On my local pc:

XML/

.env

i did:

`git rm -r XML`

`git rm -r .env`

And pushed the changes.

But that deleted the file from my pc, which i don't want.
I only want to delete is from my git.

if i now pull on production it deleted the .env en XML file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add files and folders in `gitignore`

Comment: Add file or folder names in .gitignore file

Comment: i did that but that did not delete them from the REPO they we're allready in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure the files are listed in `.gitignore` (or `.git/info/exclude`).

Then, if you want to remove files from the repository, but not from your working tree, use `git rm --cached`:

```
git rm --cached -r XML .env
git commit
```

This will stage the files for deletion, but leave the working copies intact.

Answer (score 2):

My .gitignore looks like

```
.DS_Store
nbproject/private/
app/tmp/cache/models/
app/tmp/cache/persistent/
app/tmp/cache/views/
app/tmp/logs/
```