# How Git ignore Pods/Target Support Files

Tags: git

How do I ignore files in following directory?

```
projectName/Pods/Target Support Files
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I ignore files in a directory in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527597/how-do-i-ignore-files-in-a-directory-in-git)

Comment: I tried all these options but it doesn't get solved((

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following line to gitignore file:

```
projectName/Pods/Target*Support*Files/
```

Also should work:

```
"projectName/Pods/Target Support Files/"
```