# Cleaning the Solutions for zipped email attachment

Tags: c++, solution

How do I 'clean' a Visual Studio 2010 C++ solution,

so that it is small enough to be zipped up and sent as an email attachment?

Is there any other way to send large MSVS C++ files over email?

Comment: E-mail does not impose any attachment size restrictions.

Comment: Email is neither a file transfer protocol nor a source repository. Have you considered using a [distributed version control system](http://git-scm.com/)?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions for a good list of files that you don't need to distribute with your source.

Comment: @n0rd you are actually wrong. It's a defacto, given truth that across the vast majority of SMTP servers, the maximum mail size is 10MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For making size smaller:

- Visit each project's folder and delete everything from their `bin`, `obj`, `Debug` and `Release` folders (or delete the folders themselves).

**Notice:** If some files have been manually put in the `bin` folder by the developer for the program to work make sure you don't delete it. **If it's not your own project:** Normally there are files of type `exe`, `pdb`, `ilk`, `lib`, `dll`, `exp`, `vshost.exe`, `manifest`, that can be safely deleted. But if you see other things, such as `mdf` or `mdb` databases, images, text files, etc they shouldn't be deleted.

- At the root of the solution or project there might be a big `.ncb` file which is Intellisense's database and can be safely deleted since it is recollected next time you open the project. A user options file with `.suo` is there that contains the environment and editor's layout and settings. This can be deleted too but it's usually small.
- Finally, make sure you use a good archiver. Zip is very common but is not as good as formats like gzip, bzip2 or 7-zip.

Sending projects via e-mail is nice to send your homework to the professor, but as others noted if this is a team work, you must consider using some (distributed) version control system among your team.

Comment: You're right, I haven't seen it before :blush: But now I tried it, and it didn't delete the `.ilk` link file, the `.ncb` database and `buildlog.html`. So still cleaning manually frees up more space.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't delete all files. In VS 2010, it leaves .sdf files as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending projects by e-mail, you should consider sharing them through some kind of source code management system (SCM) like Subversion, Git, Mercurial or whatever else.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Build -> Clean Solution in VS 2010, it deletes almost all of the temporary files as in this [Clean up C++ projects](http://www.thejaywalker.net/2012/01/clean-c-projects-in-vs-2010.html) article.