# Which files to include in source control or while sharing a visual studio project with others?

Tags: visual-studio

I believe the question already made some sense. To explain further, a visual studio project usually contains a solution file, project directories, some personal preferences etc. Which files should I include while using a source control (say Git) or sharing the project with a friend or colleague?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to reverse the question and think along the lines of what you should exclude since it's naturally going to be a smaller list. Looking at one of my solutions I can see that I have excluded the following:

- .svn folder
- ReSharper cache folder
- ReSharper user options file
- Visual Studio user options file
- Bin and obj folders under each project

That should get you started.