# Visual Studio Team Services + git, how to avoid useless files in the debug and obj folder

Tags: git, azure-devops

I encountered several times conflicts between .dll, .exe and some other non-code files.
In this case, what should i do for avoiding submit useless files?

Thanks

Comment: a quite complete list of what shall be ignored: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add them to the "[.gitignore](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)" file.

For example:

```
[Bb]in/
[Oo]bj/
```

will exclude the bin and obj directories that are usually output by Visual Studio.