# Is it safe to include in .gitignore Visual Studio *.tlog files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, git, gitignore

They seem not to be included in the standard .gitignore cited in [a different Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions). I am using mainly C#

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since those files usually reside in the `$(IntDir)` or `$(OutDir)` (i.e. `obj/Debug` or `bin/Debug`) they're already ignored because those folders are ignored.