# Should I add *.kproj.user to gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore, asp.net-core

With a new ASPNET5 project, there is a `.kproj.user` file which *seems* to contain user-specific properties for the new project.

Should this file be added to my `.gitignore`? Or could there be something in this file which would prevent the project from being built on another machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you can see in "[.gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2143956/6309)":

```
*.user
```

That means any `.user` file is ignored (`.kproj.user` or otherwise).

Comment: D'oh, I searched my `.gitignore` for `"kproj"`. Thanks a lot!