# FileContentIndex/ ..... Permission denied

Tags: .net, git, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjCaN.png)
I'm using WPF app (.Net framework), I just created the project, and pushed them to git, then I got this error.

I tried searching on google, chatgpt, bing, github ... and this place, but hasn't results

Comment: Please copy and paste text like that in the future.

Comment: Not just in the future, please [edit] your current question to include the error message as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a .gitignore file to safely exclude the .vs folder from git and avoid this error. That folder isnt needed in source control at all, they are just temporary files that visual studio uses and are not part of your WPF app.

Have a read of the top couple of answers to get you started - [Gitignore won't ignore .vs folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868544/gitignore-wont-ignore-vs-folder) - it includes a suggested .gitignore file that will exclude various files VS generates that should NOT be in source code. Once the .gitignore file is added and commited, any time you `git add .` git will automatically ignore that folder.