# Visual studio project settings and Git

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio, github

I have a project using Visual Studio and its being developed on two different systems, its currently a github repo. I want to be able to keep the project settings for each system independent of each other. So every time I update my code from either system, I don't want the project settings to be updated. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Keep the solution and project files neutral. You want them to be tracked when you add/remove files to your projects. Pack your individual settings to a special .props file and let your project files use the properties. Put the .props file into .gitignore and you are done.

Look here [Working with Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx) for details on using property sheets.

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` add files you do not want to share with others.
https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for documentation.
I believe, easily you can find ready to use templates for VS projects on web, so you won't have to create it by yourself (btw. creating new project in github, it will ask for if you want to have this .gitignore file, and ask what kind of project it will be, so all will be done for you).
[.gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions?rq=1)

Or simply do not commit those settings ;)