# Define project_name/Debug in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I have Visual C++ project on disc:

```
project_name.sln
/project_name/project_name.vcxproj
/project_name/Debug
/project_name/Release
```

`.gitignore` is placed in in the same directory like `project_name.sln`. Hot to tell `.gitignore` not include `/project_name/Debug` and `/project_name/Release` in universal way - without defining `project_name/` directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore for Visual Studio Projects and Solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143956/gitignore-for-visual-studio-projects-and-solutions)

Answer (score 1):

Try [gitignore.io](http://www.gitignore.io/) it can generates `.gitignore` for various scenarios. Then, point git configuration's `core.excludesfile` to point the generated `.gitignore` file.

`git config --global core.excludesfile 'GIT_IGNORE_PATH/.gitignore'`